# Scanner part of USB multifunction printer/scanner not found

Tags: drivers, usb, canon, scanner, sane

<sup>*I wrote this a year ago. Still not solved, so I have re-written it to reflect the current state.*</sup>

System:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and a Canon Pixma MG5751 multifunction printer/scanner on USB.

Problem:
Printer works perfectly. Scanner is the same USB device but not recognized by `sane`, but works fine with Canon's `scangearmp2`. The scanner has worked perfectly with Ubuntu earlier, even using Simple Scan; I have no idea what changed.

Please:
How can I get the scanner working under `sane` again?

Steps so far:

1. I have removed and re-added the printer several times.
2. I have also purged and reinstalled the Canon `cnijprinter` and `scangearmp2` packages in between.
3. Reading around [other very similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900935/simple-scan-cannot-find-scanner), I've found that my computer does recognize the device.

   - `lsusb|grep Canon` provides:
     `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04a9:178e Canon, Inc.`
   - `sane-find-scanner` finds nothing but complains about insufficient permissions.
   - `sudo sane-find-scanner|grep Canon` finds the device:
     `found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x178e [MG5700 series]) at libusb:001:003`
   - `sudo scanimage -L` does not find the scanner, and neither does Simple Scan:

> ```
> No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
> check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
> sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
> which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
> ```

I'm out of ideas. Please help! Thank you.

---

**Update based on comments:** I've installed the `sane-git` package and tested: no success. *Scangearmp2* works but *Simple Scan* still doesn't see the scanner. The `sane-git` page also linked to the latest release version `sane-release` which I also installed, and that caused a lot of promising lines like `Installing new version of config file /etc/sane.d/canon_dr.conf ...` - but the result was the same; *Scangearmp2* works but *Simple Scan* still doesn't see the scanner.

---

**Update 20190122:**
After an hour of working with `apt-get` I have now made some progress, but only partially.

- `scanimage -L` now finds the scanner, even without `sudo`:

> ```
> device `pixma:MG5700_192.168.1.81' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MG5700 Series multi-function peripheral
> device `pixma:04A9178E_733AA7' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MG5700 Series multi-function peripheral
> ```

- When I start Simple-Scan, it does not immediately complain about *no scanner found.* This is good.
- When I start a scan, it complains: *Failed to scan: Error communicating with scanner.*
- In Simple-Scan > Document > Preferences, I see that there are two scanners listed, and the first one is selected. I selected the second choice and tried again = **SUCCESS!** I guess it doesn't like the network scanner but USB works. I'm happy!

Comment: and if you type `scangearmp2` in a terminal, does that load Canon's programme called ScanGearMP and does it see the device?

Comment: beyond that; the developers of sane will often recommend installing the latest release of sane from here https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git and another useful thing may be to join their mailing list: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel and they may be best able to advise if their newest version does not help

Comment: I had similar problems with a multifunction Canon device, but it was networked, not USB.  It is working well now, everything works except the ADF with sane. I did so much stuff to try and fix it that I have no idea what actually worked. For a long time I used the rolfsbensch ppa; I think that did help, but in 18.04 it isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

> The sane-pixma library implements a  SANE  (Scanner  Access  Now 
>   Easy)
>          backend  that  provides access to Canon PIXMA / i-SENSYS / imageCLASS /
>          imageRUNNER multi-function devices (All-in-one printers) and the  Canon
>          CanoScan  Flatbed/TPU  scanners.   The  backend implements both the USB
>          interface and network interface (using Canon's  BJNP  and  MFNP  proto
>          cols).  The  network  interface  supports scanners over IPv4 as well as
>          IPv6 (MFNP over IPv6 is untested).

This backend is required in order to get your scanner to work under sane

While I do not have your scanner and cannot test, it appears that you are missing the libsane-pixma.so library that supports the Canon Pixma MG5700 series for sane. The package that contains it is [libsane-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsane-dev), is in the repositories and can be installed with the command `sudo apt install libsane-dev`

You can confirm that you have the file with the command `find /usr -name *.so | grep pixma`

Sources:

http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsane-dev

Comment: Solved! It works now. I still don't have the path `/usr/local/lib/sane/` you mention but I'll grant you the reward anyway :-)